# How to integrate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\,\ln^3x}x\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-functions, euler-sums

How to integrate $$\displaystyle{\Large\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1+x)\,\ln^3x}x\mathrm{d}x}$$

### My idea

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x) \ln^3 x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x &= -18 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( -1 \right )^{n+1} \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^2 - \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left (n+2  \right )^4}  \\
&= 18 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^2 - \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left ( n+2 \right )^4} \\
&= 18 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \left ( \mathcal{H}_{n}^2 -  \mathcal{H}_{n+1}^{(2)} \right ) \frac{1}{\left ( n+1 \right )^4}
\end{align*}

Comment: Probably a close-form involves imaginary part of polylogarithms of a complex number and some more friendly numbers (among them probably a rational multiple of zeta(7))

Comment: Solution by MultiPolylog: $$36 \text{MultiPolylog}(\{5,1,1\},\{-1,1,1\})$$ See: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GeneralizedPolylog&cid=388

Comment: And what is the closed-form in terms of "simple" polylogarithms according to Maple?

Comment: @FDP. Maple doesn't know.